# Create responsive site icon using bootstrap

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, master-page, image, responsive

I am using bootstrap to create a responsive master page in SharePoint. I want to create a responsive image. I have applied the img responsive class to the image but is does not show any sort of responsive behavior.

I am unable to figure out why this class is not affecting the site icon.

Comment: is the bootstrap css been overridden by some other css ? check in browser console by hitting F12, keep height and width in % instead of px

Comment: where have you included your bootstrap reference.?

Comment: try inspect element in your browser do you see your class applied to image or is there any wrapper around it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24446/discussion-between-mancy-desaee-and-inferno).